# Setting the same seed for torch, random number and numpy throughout all the modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, random-seed

I am trying to set the same seed throughout all the project.
Below are the parameters I am setting in my main file, in which all other modules will be imported -

```
seed = 42
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
# Torch RNG
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
# Python RNG
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
```

My project directory looks like below -

```
├── Combined_Files_without_label5.csv
├── __pycache__
│   ├── dataset.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── datasets.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── testing.cpython-37.pyc
├── datasets.py
├── import_packages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── dataset.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── dataset_class.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── dataset_partition.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── visualising.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── dataset_class.py
│   ├── dataset_partition.py
│   └── visualising.py
├── main.py
```

Now, the problem is I am importing the module from `dataset_partition.py` and the function  needs a `seed` value there. e.g -

```
    df_train, df_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(X,
                                                      y,
                                                      stratify=y,
                                                      test_size=(1.0 - frac_train), # noqa
                                                      random_state=seed)
```

Now, my questions are,
 1)If I just remove the `random_state` parameter from the above statement so will it take the seed from my main file?
 If not, then how to set it? 
2)Does all the other function which requires seed like `torch.manual.seed`, `torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)` will behave in the same way?(If not, then how to resolve it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)If I just remove the random_state parameter from the above statement
> so will it take the seed from my main file?

Yes, as the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random-state) for default (`None`) value say:

> Use the global random state instance from numpy.random. Calling the
> function multiple times will reuse the same instance, and will produce
> different results.

As you are using this in `__init__` I suppose, it will be run before any other function you use from your package and you are fine.

> 2)Does all the other function which requires seed
> like torch.manual.seed, torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed) will behave in
> the same way?

Yes, those will set global seed for Python and PyTorch to use and you are also fine here.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My main code script looks like below, I am calling all the other modules in main but some of them are also interdependent on each other and then I call main.e.g is in the script -  https://pastiebin.com/5f672e5db6b72

Comment: @Mark you can import all modules at the top as PEP suggests, __provided they do not make any operation__, so any function definitions, classes and so on are fine. If they do make some computations like splitting `train_test` on import (probably not, as it's usually not the case and usually bad practice) you are fine with the imports where they currently are.

Comment: Thank You, I just changed the file structure and instead of importing the module into another and then importing in main, I just restructured them to import in main.